# Problem with pass data to controller - update data

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a problem with passing data from view to controller... When I was clicked button which sending POST - I have got only data for Category.Name. No subcategories, no ids etc. I am thinking I do something wrong with my view but i am not sure...

I need really help. Thanks for everything comments.

---

That is my View:

```
@model AplikacjaFryzjer_v2.Models.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edytuj kategorię";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var SubcategoriesData = (IList<AplikacjaFryzjer_v2.Models.Subcategory>)ViewBag.Subcategories;
}

<h1>Edytuj kategorię</h1>


<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input asp-for="Name" disabled class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="update">Aktualizuj kategorię</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @if (SubcategoriesData != null)
            {
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-form-label">
                    <div id="subcatContainer">
                        @foreach (var subcategory in SubcategoriesData.ToList())
                        {
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input asp-for="@subcategory.Name" />
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Usuń</button>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@subcategory.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add">Dodaj podkategorię</button>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="container" class="col-md-6">
                    <label id="labelName">Nazwa podkategorii</label>
                    <input id="inputName" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="addNew">Dodaj</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            // Variables
            var i = @SubcategoriesData.Count()-1;
           
            // Add rows to the form
            $("#add").click(function (e) {
                var html = '<p /><div class="form-group col-sm-6"><input asp-for="Subcategories[' + i + '].Name" /><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Usuń</button></div>';
                i++;
                $("#subcatContainer").append(html).before();
            });

            // Remove rows from the form
            $("#subcatContainer").on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
                i--;
                $(this).parent('div').remove();

            });

            // Populate values from the first row
        });
    </script>
```

My Actions EditCategory in controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult EditCategory(int Id)
        {
            var category = _categoriesRepository.GetCategory(Id);

            if (category == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Kategoria o id = {Id} nie została odnaleziona";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            ViewBag.Subcategories = category.Subcategories;
            return View(category);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditCategory(Category category)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // store Subcategories data which has been added
                ViewBag.Subcategories = category.Subcategories == null ? new List<Subcategory>() { } : category.Subcategories;
                return View("EditCategory");

            }
            _categoriesRepository.UpdateCategory(category);
            return RedirectToAction("ManageCategories");
        }
```

And my object (model):

```
    public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Subcategories {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have got only data for Category.Name. No subcategories, no ids etc.

Based on your `Category` model class, the property `Subcategories` is defined as `List<Subcategory>`, to make form data values that browser user post could be automatically bound to this property, you can modify the field of Subcategories related to `<input asp-for="@Subcategories[i].Name" />` as below.

```
@model AplikacjaFryzjer_v2.Models.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edytuj kategorię";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var Subcategories = (IList<AplikacjaFryzjer_v2.Models.Subcategory>)ViewBag.Subcategories;
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">

        @*code for other fields*@

        <div class="col">
            @if (Subcategories != null)
            {
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-form-label">
                    <div id="subcatContainer">
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Subcategories.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input asp-for="@Subcategories[i].Name" />
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Usuń</button>
                                <span asp-validation-for="@Subcategories[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add">Dodaj podkategorię</button>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="container" class="col-md-6">
                    <label id="labelName">Nazwa podkategorii</label>
                    <input id="inputName" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="addNew">Dodaj</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

***Update:***

> why new inputs added by jquery not sending to my controller? I have got "" in my code jquery

As I mentioned in comment, please not use tag helper syntax on js client. You can try to manually set `name` and `value` attribute for new generated input field(s)
like below.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    // Variables
    var i = @Subcategories.Count();
           
    // Add rows to the form
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        //var html = '<p /><div class="form-group col-sm-6"><input asp-for="Subcategories[' + i + '].Name" /><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Usuń</button></div>';
        var html = '<p /><div class="form-group col-sm-6"><input name="Subcategories[' + i + '].Name" value="" /><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Usuń</button></div>';
        i++;
        $("#subcatContainer").append(html).before();
    });

    // Remove rows from the form
    $("#subcatContainer").on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
        i--;
        $(this).parent('div').remove();

    });

    // Populate values from the first row
});
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: And to fix this issue, you can also to create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample) to implement custom model binding based on your model class and posted data.

Comment: but is not my issue, my issue is - why new inputs added by jquery not sending to my controller? I have got "<input asp-for="Subcategories[' + i + '].Name" />" in my code jquery

Comment: JS code is running on browser client side, please not use tag helper like syntax on js client, you can manually set `name` and `value` attribute for input field.

Comment: Manually? But how?

Comment: Hi @Krispekowy, any updates about this case? Have you resolved the problem.